# SQLite - System.Data.SQLite.2012 empty

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I've downloaded **sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.94.1.zip** from SQLite website.

However, when I opened the **SQLite.NET.2012.sln** and noticed that the project **System.Data.SQLite.2012** was empty, **none of the source files** (eg. **SQLiteConnection.cs**) was included in the project.  (These files did exist in the file system but they are not included in any project of the solution.)  The project can be built successfully and the System.Data.SQLite.dll could be generated.  Not sure where did its content come from.

I was totally confused that how this could happen?  Can any body help me?  I want to modify the SQLiteConnection class and recompile the System.Data.SQLite.dll.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something missing from SQLite source code for the Visual Studio 2012 to parse the csproject file correctly.
After manually change the csproject file's xml content.  I've successfully included the files into the project and built successfully.  The DLL generated can be used then.